# Make a notification have options

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Let's say I have my notification set up but I want it to do something special. I want the notification to pop up and it would ask a question. I want you to be able to click yes or no and the yes where yes would trigger an action and so would the no, but the yes wouldn't open the app. And I want it to be able to be answered from my lock screen. Is this possible? If so, either how or maybe a tutorial to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that without launching the app, but there's a way to read parameters and options on `applicationDidLaunchWithOptions:`. Might be worth investigating. Here's a good tutorial on push notifications:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2